# Using a loop to export data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data with classes A, B,and C. I need to export each class separately to excel. Until now I have been running `Select * From foo WHERE class = 'A';` and I would export the data and then change the where statement to `WHERE class = 'B'` and do the same for C.

I am new to SQL and I know that a VBA-esque loop will not work.

Is there a way that I can create a loop that can run statement with class A, export the data, change the class to B and repeat?

Comment: Why not VBA though. You can `ADODB` build the recordset, do `Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset yourRecordset` and loop to the next one.

Comment: The data resides in sql and I was hoping to be able to do everything in one fell swoop.

Comment: How are you exporting the data?

Comment: Into a csv file using the file>export option

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @class varchar(10);
DECLARE cur CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR 
SELECT -- your list of classes to loop through


OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @class

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    --do your export

    SQLCMD -S SERVERNAME -E -Q "Select * From foo WHERE class = @class"
    -s "," -o "D:\MyData.csv" 

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO  @class
END

CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
```

or you can use bcp method to export to csv in your loop

```
bcp "SELECT blah blah blah" queryout "D:\MyTable.csv" -c -t , -S SERVERNAME -T
```